# How do you automatically enable ACM for Heroku review apps?

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to get review apps up and running on Heroku. In my usecase I have a bunch of custom domains and I have postdeploy and pr-predestroy scripts that correctly setup all of that. However ACM is not getting enabled for the new apps, so none of the URL's gets certs until someone goes and manually enables ACM. Is there a way to have ACM automatically enabled for new review apps? If it matters any we are manually triggering the creation of the review apps.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I found was to use the platform API to enable ACM from the postdeploy script https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#app-enable-acm